# Display image and name from two python list using html page with a for loop?

Tags: python, html, loops, flask

I have two lists which is returned from python flask script using render_template to the HTML page.
first list contains images : pics = [] 
second list contains names : names = []

so what I did was :

```
<table>
                {% set i = 0 %}
                {% for x in pics: %}                    
                <tr>                        
                    <td>
                    <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ x}}" width="100" height="100">
                    </td>                        
                    <td>                           
                        {{ names[i] }} </h3> 
                         {% set i = i+1 %}                          
                    </td>                        
                </tr>                         
                {% endfor %}
</table>
```

The output which I am getting is (within a table format) :

pic1 name1

pic2 name1

Output which I am expecting is (within a table format) :

pic1 name1

pic2 name2

Any help will be appreciated....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try iterating using the `range`

**Ex:**

```
<table>
    {% for x in range(A|length ) %}                    
        <tr>                        
            <td>{{ A[x] }}</td>                        
            <td>{{ B[x] }}</td>          
        </tr>                         
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Appologies Rajesh I thought the dummy data will help me so I changed the question. can you help me with the edit.